# How do I do additional tests after expected exceptions are thrown?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to verify that the object's state is not affected by a mutator call that is expected to generate an error. I thought I could do:

```
function testWhatever(){
   try{
      // setup $obj
      $this->expectException(WhateverException::CLASS);
      // code that throws
   }finally{
      // assert that $obj's state is still valid
   }
}
```

But I immediately realized it would certainly create some issues with PHPUnit (and it indeed does) if the code within `finally` also throws for whatever reason.

What are my options to perform some assertions after the exception has thrown, possibly without being too acrobatic with try/catch/rethrow and without repeating "code that throws" twice? Something with equivalent functionality to the following, which is not allowed:

```
function testWhatever(){
   try{
      // setup $obj
      $this->expectException(WhateverException::CLASS);
      // code that throws
   }finally{
      $this->expectException(null); 
      // assert that $obj's state is still valid
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an ordinary `try` / `catch` / `finally`

```
function testFoobar()
{
    // setup code
    try {
        // code that throws
        $this->fail("Code didn't throw!");
    } catch (ExpectedException $e) {
        // verify exception message
    } finally {
        // verify other things
    }
}
```

Comment: was looking for something less unconventional for phpunit tests but i don't think i have more options...

Answer (score 0):

You could use two tests and make them depend on each other (just make your first test succeed on `Exception`

```
/**
 * @depends testWhatever
 */
public function testSomethingAfterException() {
     // more tests to run
}
```